# Mixed effects model for longitudinal data

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, panel-data, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I have the following data: a group of patients for which I measure blood pressure (bp) 1 hour before treatment where they are given a placebo, then during treatment with the drug, and then 1 hour after treatment where they are given the placebo again.

Here's an illustration of the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(patient = letters[1:5], bp_before = rnorm(5,180,1), bp_during = rnorm(5,220,50), bp_after = rnorm(5,180,15))
```

Or perhaps the data should be written as:

```
df <- data.frame(patient = rep(letters[1:5],3), bp = c(rnorm(5,180,1),rnorm(5,220,50),rnorm(5,180,15)), time = c(rep(0,5),rep(1,5),rep(10,5)), treatment = c(rep("placebo",5),rep("drug",5),rep("placebo",5)))
```

[image]

I'm looking for a linear (longitudinal?) model (or glm) to quantify the effect of the drug on bp, accounting for the bp pressure before and after the treatment. I imagine patient should also be treated as a random effect.